# How to Retrieve Lat Long of BEACON?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm Trying to get the exact lat & long of a Bluetooth based BEACON Device in JAVA File using "getBuetoothDevice()" function. We  can get the Lat & Long using Kotlin for all Android versions.

But we're facing problem  when we try the same function in a Java File for Android-Studio 3.1.2

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: You should show your code.

Comment: I do not think it is possible to get the lat and lon of a bluetooth beacon without using a third party web service.  If you have sonehow done this in Kotlin, please show that code and a Java conversion should be trivial.

Comment: if (rssi == 0) {
                    return -1.0; // if we cannot determine distance, return -1.
                }

                double ratio = rssi*1.0/txPower;
                if (ratio < 1.0) {
                    return Math.pow(ratio,10);
                }
                else {
                    double accuracy =  (0.89976)*Math.pow(ratio,7.7095) + 0.111;
                    return accuracy;
                }

Comment: @davidgyoung Hi David, Thanks for your response, can you please provide us a example or reference of any third party web service which we can use for this. We have run the exact parameter in Kotlin, please suggest a way of how we can do the same using Java.

Comment: To be clear, your comment above shows kotlin code for calculating an estimated distance not Lat/Long as the title and first sentence of the question suggests.  Are you trying to get an estimated distance or a latitude and longitude coordinate?

Comment: @davidgyoung I am trying to get the Lat Long Co-ordinates but we didn't get. So I just get the alternate with getDistance().

Comment: Can you please clarify this statement: "We can get the Lat & Long using Kotlin for all Android versions".  Is this true?